# How to solve combinations in card game for n people in r rounds (just one encounter)

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, playing-cards

There is a famous card game in Germany called **"Doppelkopf"**.
Usually, you play **"Doppelkopf"** with **4** players, but you can also play it with a table of **5** players, where one player is just watching.
(Where everyone "has the cards" once in a round, meaning everyone has the right to play the first card once every round.)
Every year, my family organizes a "Doppelkopf" tournament with **3** rounds (`r`).
Depending on the availabilty of my relatives, every year the number of participants varies.
Expecting a minimun of participant of **16** people, the number (`n`) in this experiment can rise up unlimited (as does the number of rounds `r`).
**Naturally, my relatives do not want to be paired with someone twice, since they want to exchange gossip most efficiently!**
There we have:
`n` - Participants 
`r`- Rounds

```
    t_total = n // 4                    # Total Tables (round down of n)
    t_5 = n % 4                         # Tables of 5s
    t_4 = t_total - t_5                 # Tables of 4s
    pos_pair = n * (n - 1) / 2          # possible pairs (n over 2)
    nec_pair = (t_5 * 10 + t_4 * 6) * r # necessary pairs
```

I was instructed with the aim to minimize the encounters (if possible to set encounters == 1 for everyone)!
Since, I do not want to solve the problem for P{n={16, ..., 32}, r=3} (which I did for some cases), **but to solve it with any given P{n∈N, r∈N}** , there is a discrepancy between my abilities and the requirements for a solution!

Therefore, I would like to ask the **community** to help me with this problem, **to solve it for any given P{n∈N, r∈N}! 

And also to prove, if this problem is not solvable for any P{n∈N, r∈N}, which is given** "`if pos_pair < nec_pair`".

Here are two solutions for **P{n=20, r=3}**:

which very much solves my **"Doppelkopf"** tournament problem:

`('Best result was ', [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]], [[16, 12, 8, 18], [13, 1, 5, 9], [15, 4, 17, 6], [2, 19, 7, 10], [3, 11, 20, 14]], [[14, 9, 17, 7], [13, 20, 8, 2], [5, 4, 12, 19], [6, 16, 11, 1], [15, 18, 10, 3]]])


('Best result was ', [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20]], [[19, 11, 13, 3], [2, 15, 9, 8], [1, 16, 18, 6], [14, 7, 17, 10], [4, 12, 20, 5]], [[17, 8, 3, 12], [20, 9, 16, 7], [15, 11, 6, 4], [2, 13, 10, 18], [1, 19, 14, 5]]])`


But in order to solve this problem with an arbitrary `n` and `r` I have come to no conclusion. 
In my opinion, there are three ways to go about this problem in a computational solution or approximation.

1. First, you can iterate about rounds, and assign every player to a
   table without having collision, remembering pairs and appeareances
   in total (not to exeed total rounds)
2. Secondly, you can iterate about tables, which seems to be helpful with participants, that are a multiple of 2 **(see for P{n=16, r=5}**
   https://matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=85206&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)

   - also remeber pairs and appearances, but mainly follow a certain
     patters as described in the link, which I somehow can not scale to
     other numbers!!
3. There is somehow a mathemathical way to descibe this procedure and conclude a solution

Even though, this is more of a mathematical question (and I don't know where to ask those questions), I am interested in the algorithmic solution!

Comment: It's a hard problem, with deep math, some constraint satisfaction algos, and a lot of unknowns. What's known about it is published under the keyword "Social Golfer Problem" and variants.

Comment: That's and NP-problem, you can find plenty of documentation online, probably you'll want to start with an heuristic

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks! I had a hard time formulating this problem, in order to find solutions or approaches to it! The keyword "Social Golfer Problem" is very helpful.